# Having trouble understanding how to calculate the volume of revolution solid

Tags: integration

Suppose I'm given $y=x^2,y=9$ and $x\ge0$ rotating on the y axis.

I need to use the pipe formula, so I would need to solve

$2\pi\int_{0}^{3} x(9-x^2)dx$

From what I've been told, the x multiplier in my formula should be $(x-c)$ or $(c-x)$ depending wheter the region is located at the left or right of $x=c$. Also, $(9-x^2)$ should be $(f(x)-g(x))$.

I don't understand how to know if the region is located at the left or right of $x=c$ (why in this case it only becomes x?) and I also don't understand why $f(x)$ is simply replaced by 9 in this example.

Would someone please give me some explanation on this ?

Thanks.

Comment: The "$x$ multiplier" is the "radius," and must be non-negative.

Comment: @Dr.MV In other words, I should not really bother about wheter it is at the left/right, but instead simply switch to make sure it is never negative ?

Comment: I need to understand better what $c$ is.  The body of revolution is defined by a region in a plane.  The region is bounded by some "regular" closed contour.  In some typical problems, the contour is specified by component parts.  In the problem here, one of those parts was the segment $y=9$, $0\le\ x\le 3$.  Another component was the segment $x=0$, $0\le y \le 9$. The third and final component was the curve $y=x^2$, $0\le x\le 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually think about the geometry. Each slice is a cylinder with radius equal to the distance of the $x$-coordinate from the axis of revolution $x=c$ (in this case the axis of revolution is $x=0$), and height the distance from the lower to the upper function. In this case you are integrating from $g(x) = x^2$ to $f(x) = 9$.

If you were revolving this region around the line $x=-2$ (draw yourself a picture), the distance from the axis of revolution at any $x$-coordinate is $x+2$, so the integral would be
\begin{equation*}
  2\pi\int_0^3 (x+2)(9-x^2)\,dx.
\end{equation*}
If you were revolving around the line $x=5$, the distance from the axis of revolution is $5-x$, so the integral would be 
\begin{equation*}
  2\pi\int_0^3 (5-x)(9-x^2)\,dx.
\end{equation*}

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but don't you mean around the line $y=-2$ ?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand. This answer really helped me.. Thanks a lot.